# generate change log without Getter

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture

Reading through the internet, I see a lot of people saying **Getter/Setter** is evil. you need to hide the data as private and only provide functions and use messages between objects to do work. I try to do this to **Setters** in my code with some success, but when it comes to **Getters** there are always cases this is not possible: the data within the class can't be in the memory forever, you always need to persistent it.

One case that comes quite often is: when you try to update an entity and need to generate a change log, you need to compare the two objects, without Getters, how can you accomplish this?

Same with persistent into the database(maybe I can have it to generate a PO object)

**Edit:**

Maybe I can frame it like this: in DDD I want my Entity to have as few Getters as possible, but in the infrastructure layer, in need to persistent it , I have to expose all the data

Comment: How are getters/setters evil for objects that are only supposed to hold/share data? Not every variable needs public accessors, but if you make everything private you are forced to have all the logic in 1 class.

Answer (score 0):

I think I do not understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, but I will try to elaborate on a few things that I assume that could help.

Getters and Setters are in no way evil; on the contrary, they are fundamental concepts of Java. Not all fields of a class have to be private. It is a decision based on what you are trying to express with your code and how instances of that class should be used. You should refrain to write Getters and Setters that do anything else but just get or set a value.

That being said, in most cases it is good practice to use private member variables and write Getters (and sometimes Setters) to access the data within an instances of that class. Imagine an instance of a class as a capsule for data that bundles information that you need in a certain context. Ask yourself, why should any other Object from another context have direct access to the data within that instance - or even manipulate it? Manipulation of the instance's data should ideally be done by the instance itself, through methods provided by the class. Why? Only the instance itself knows its context and only the instance itself knows exactly which purpose its fields express in that context. In this line of thinking private fields help to design cleaner and more expressive code. They help keeping track of what your classes' purpose is. You should always consciously decide which data should be read (getter) and, if needed, which data should be directly written (setter) from outside.

I don't know what exactly your changelog should contain. If you are using a database, there is a good chance you might have access to an auditing framework that could help you with tracking changes. Otherwise I would recommend to use an Aspect Oriented approach for the classes in question. See [this short introduction for AspectJ](https://www.baeldung.com/aspectj) to get an idea of the concept.

Comment: when it comes to database, I have to expose all my data, but for other cases i don't want to , the problem is i only have one class: either expose all or not at all .

Comment: Are you saying that you cannot use private member variables in an Entity class? Why is that? Which JPA implementation are you using?